# Hostname change during database migration

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, web-applications, database-migration

We have been migrating database from host to new host, that requires applications to update the databse hostname accordingly. I don't think it is a good or right way. Would you like to share your expereince in such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) for each database.  Always reference the CNAME in the connection strings instead of the host name.  When the databases change hosts simply change the CNAME, there's no need to change the application connect strings.